# What kind of binary file is this?

Tags: python, com, binaryfiles

I'm attempting to read this binary file using Python, and I'm seeing this.  Does this type of data look like anything to anyone?

I've read somewhere that \x00 is a null character... which gives me hope that I can read this file using Python.

I've also been told this is a COM object, although I'm not sure how that translates to how I can read this file.

```
In []: afd

Out []:  b"AFD\x1a  ALFA Factor File 3.0                      Y\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x00\x00\x00!\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004\x08\x00\x00U\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8a\x00\x00\x00                x\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x08\x03 \x03,\x84\xfdSz\x9a`\x1f\x90y\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd4\x1d \xd9q+x\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x08\x03 \x03,\x84\xfdSz\x9a`\x1f\x90y\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd4\x1d \xd9q+x\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x08\x03 \x03,\x84\xfdSz\x9a`\x1f\x90y\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd4\x1d \xd9q+x\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x08\x03 \x03,\x84\xfdSz\x9a`\x1f\x90y\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd4\x1d \xd9q+x\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nx\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x08\x03 \x03,\x84\xfdSz\x9a`\x1f\x90y\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd4\x1d \xd9q+x\x9c\xed\xc11\x01\x00\x00\x04\x000\x01\x84\x10E\x13\xfd[xT\xf0m\xcb8=]\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbb\x05'\x0er\nAnnExp                                                                          (t)                 Real      0122   |                                                                                  ****  *****A*******                                                 d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****C*******                                                 \x89\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****D*******                                                 \xae\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****E*******                                                 \xd3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****G*******                                                 \xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****I*******                                                 \x1d\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****K*******                                                 B\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****L*******                                                 g\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****M*******                                                 \x8c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****O*******                                                 \xb1\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****P*******                                                 \xd6\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****Q*******                                                 \xfb\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****R*******                                                 A\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****S*******                                                  \x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****T*******                                                 b\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****U*******                                                 \x87\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****V*******                                                 \xa8\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****W*******                                                 \xc9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****X*******                                                 \xee\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****Y*******                                                 \x13\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   ****  *****Z*******                                                 4\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94\x13\x00\x00\x00   Add new variables: AnnExp on 06-15-2018 at 07:20:15\rInitialize from V:\\VATest\\2018Q1\\Q2BOP\\step9\\AnnExp.afd.txt on 06-15-2018 at 07:20:15\r"
```

Comment: This isn't really a Python question at all. What OS do you see this on? Does the file have a file extension? Where did the file come from? You can read a binary file in most computer languages I know of, as long as you use the correct functions and options. Python has no special capability for reading null (zero) binary values than most other languages, in particular. And reading the file has nothing to do with its type. Interpreting the contents, however, depends very much on its type. But you are just talking about reading. Unclear what you're really after here...

Comment: The `^Z` is a common feature of magic numbers for compatibility with DOS.  If the date at the end is accurate, maybe you can still find the author?

Comment: @lurker thank you for your reply.  The file has an extension 'afd', which is specific to a certain software that's very industry specific.  I was told by support that this is a binary file and a COM object, so I think it's a less exotic filetype that just so happens to have a unique extension.

I'm looking to interpret the contents, particularly to parse the file if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: What kind of information do you hope to get from reading the binary file?